# How to use swagger with play?

Tags: playframework-2.0, swagger

I have seen [this](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/scala-play2/) sample application and I am interested to use swagger on a play 2 application. So I included dependencies in my Build.scala like that project does:

```
    val appDependencies: Seq[sbt.ModuleID] = Seq(
    "com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2-utils" % "1.1.1")

  val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
    resolvers := Seq(
      "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",
      Resolver.url("swagger-core-github-repo", url("http://wordnik.github.com/repository"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns),
      "sonatype-releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
      "sonatype-snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
      "java-net" at "http://download.java.net/maven/2",
      "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"))
```

but it gives me unresolved dependencies.

I have also tried:

```
"com.wordnik" % "swagger-play2-1.1.1" % "1.1.1"
```

because I use Play 2.1-RC1 but still it does not find it.

Does anyone know where I am wrong (I think I have some error on this last tried from above..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Wordnik repo](https://github.com/wordnik/wordnik.github.com/tree/master/repository/com.wordnik/swagger-play2_2.9.1/1.1.1), it seems that it should be:

```
"com.wordnik" % "swagger-play2_2.9.1" % "1.1.1"
```

But since the module has been built on Play 2.0.x, I don't know if it will work with Play 2.1

Comment: Thanks you are right... but yes, I don't think it will work with 2.1. Would be so nice if developers of modules kept in sync with play releases...

Answer (score 3):

Today swagger-core-1.2.0 was released and is now synced to maven central.  So with the latest version, you can now add the following dependency, and remove the `swagger-core-github-repo`:

```
"com.wordnik" %% "swagger-play2" % "1.2.0"
```

Note the current release is only scala 2.9.1

We're looking at Play 2.1-RC1 currently.  If you're hitting a specific issue, could you please hit #swagger in IRC or submit the error message on github?

UPDATE

play 2.1 is supported in this branch:

https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/tree/scala_2.10.0

And is available in sonatype:

https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/wordnik/swagger-play2_2.10/1.2.1-SNAPSHOT/

We'll push a release version after play 2.1 gets out of rc.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I am putting the post to the right question. I have just finished migrating a project from Play 2.2.3 to Play 2.3.10, in which I was struggling getting to Swagger 1.3.12 to work with Play 2.3.10, and I would like to share my research and benefit other people as I benefitted from here. If you are trying to upgrade to swagger **1.3.12**, you have to use the right version of reflections library, i.e. **0.9.8**, otherwise it won't work.

The reason is that Swagger 1.3.12 automatically brings in reflections 0.9.9 and **Play** will evict the old version(s) of it. To me, version 0.9.9 is supposed to work well with the new swagger, but it doesn't. After couple rounds of trial and error, I found that the version 0.9.8 works. As I said the old version will be evicted so you have to force it, and you can force the version as follows:

```
"org.reflections" % "reflections" % "0.9.8" force()
```

After doing this, our project compiles and runs successfully and the Swagger API Doc page is displayed properly. For more details, please visit my blog http://jackypig0906.wixsite.com/linghung/single-post/2016/10/06/Migrate-Play-22-to-Play-23.